# What to cover in a "introduction to python" talk?

Tags: programming-languages, python, team

I'm in a student team that is focusing on web development. My teammates are interested in Python and I'm the only one that has learned it, so I was asked to give an "introduction to Python" talk next week.

I'd like to listen to your advice about what to talk about to make the talk interesting instead of just a bunch of grammar things.

PS: my teammates are familiar with PHP and .NET

Comment: Well, they like to eat mice and tend to sleep in the sun or on warm rocks. They love to coil around people and be petted but be wary if they haven't been fed in a while...oh wait, you meant the language. Nevermind.

Answer (score 6):

I'll try to express my opinion as a plan:

- **WTF?**
  Full article on comparing it to the PHP is here: http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonVsPhp I think it is the best to compare it at first to something they know. Acctualy this article alone is enough to tell what is python.
- **Why?**
  Here is nice article on advantages of python: http://www.webdotdev.com/nvd/content/view/1073/ and forum thread for mixed opinions http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=624352
- **How?**
  Python wiki provides nice tutorial: http://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide
  Also really good book: http://diveintopython.org/
  And interactive tutorial: http://www.learnpython.org/*
- **Problems?**
  nice thread/topic/question is here: [What are the drawbacks of Python?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/15468/what-are-the-drawbacks-of-python)

P.S. if some one asks:

- **B-b-but i'm a web developer!?**
  http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ you can build almost any web client with it
  https://www.djangoproject.com/ Take a good look at this one. I'm creating web pages with this one and its the best thing i've touched. More of Django samples:  http://www.djangosites.org/
  For prototyping - http://aspen.io/simplates/

Answer (score 6):

Code Kata.

Actually build an actual web page using an actual framework in front of their eyes.

Don't talk about "Python the language".

Show Python as it's used to build a web page.  Digress to answer questions.  Focus on building something that works.

Explain what it means and why it's cool while you are typing.

Answer (score 1):

I'd take a look at the first couple of classes from [Google's Python course](http://code.google.com/edu/languages/google-python-class/). That was one of the better 30,000 ft Python overviews I've seen. The exercises are also good examples of the kind of problem solving that Python is really useful for.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the emphasises in python are quite different to other languages so I think that it might be a good idea to cover the techniques that aren't necessarily unique to python, but that pythonistas use regularly like:

- generators,
- decorators,
- duck-typing,